# Saving remote image with a headless browser on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I trying to find a way to save a remote image with a headless browser (like PhantomJs using poltergeist) on ruby.

I dont need to save image using "net::http", or "uri.parse open".

I'm looking just saving an image with a headless browser on ruby.

I looked all over the web and also asked on irc chat but there is no one who knows to save an image with headless browser on rails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can't be done directly unless the driver supports it (which it probably doesn't)

Answer (score 0):

You may save part of webpage with [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) which is extension on top of phantomjs.

From poltergeist documentation:

```
save_screenshot('/path/to/file.png', :selector => '#id')
```

However, poltergeist is supposed to work under [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), not sure if you can adopt it for your use (your tags says you know about poltergeist).